# How to force excell to maintain field type as text when sending only numbers in C#

Tags: c#, excel

i am trying to send some data from a barcode onto an excel sheet through C#.
I set and define the columns as text, because i need them to be so later on when i retrieve the data.
But since it is only detecting numbers, excel is forcing the field type to be set as General.
Is there any way for me to force it to keep the field type always as text? Any line i can send through C#?
Thankyou in advanced.

Comment: Can you just add an apostrophe `'` in front of the number? That should work. So send `12345` as `'12345`. That's how excel interprets "anything" as text.

Comment: @mehow - good duplicate. I should have checked the right hand bar before doing anything else...

Comment: @Floris no worries. I too sometimes answer before checking duplicates... it just feels natural I guess hehe still voting to close as a duplicate is the correct action to do in the end whether the question has an answer or not :)

Comment: Sorry people, but still, thankyou for responding

Comment: Also, i didn't find he same words to express what i wanted as the original, so i wouldn't probably find it and end up asking it anyway. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want Excel to interpret anything you put in a cell as text, the simplest method is to add an apostrophe in front of the entry. This can be useful if you write a bulleted list, for example. Excel would interpret

```
- this is the first point
```

as an equation (since it starts with a minus sign, right?). This will result in a `#NAME?` error. However, it will interpret

```
'- this is the second point
```

as text - and it will show in the cell without the `'` visible. See:

[image]

Using the same idea, you could simply prepend an apostrophe to the numbers you send from C# to excel - so if you want to send `12345`, use the string `'12345`.

I am sure you know how to do that in C#

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
int val = 12345;
Range r = worksheet.Range("A1");
r.Value = "'" + val.ToString();
```